# Txt files merging while adding file name extensions

Tags: list, command-line, copy, window, txt

`96467,2`

`96466,3`

`93015,1`

`4466,1`

`90721,1`

`96239,1`

`96241,1`

`93024,1`

Hey guys, I hope you are all fine.
I have numerous text files containing lists similar to the one shown above. Previously, I ought to merge these lists into a single text file using the command-line script:

```
copy *.txt merged_file.txt
```

Now, I want to improve this process by appending the names of the respective text files next to each item when copying them to the new merged file. The desired output format should have each item followed by the name of the file it originated from, separated by a hash sign (#). For clarity, the format should look like this:

`96467,2#19.txt`

`96466,3#19.txt`

`93015,1#19.txt`

`4466,1#19.txt`

`90721,1#KAfa.txt`

`96239,1#KAfa.txt`

`96241,1#KAfa.txt`

`93024,1#KAfa.txt`

`93022,1#Tall.txt`

I appreciate any kind of help.

I expect that my issue be solved through command line commmand without the use of python.

Comment: Don't you think adding windows tag could be interesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    echo "$(<"$file")#$file" | tee new_file.txt
done
cat new_file.txt
```

Comment: Hey dear, it seems like the solution you provided is working by your side, but I'm now encountering an issue trying with your command prompt. It's saying that certain commands aren't recognized, or perhaps it's related to pasting multiple lines as a single prompt. Right now, I'm unable to proceed until I resolve this issue on my Windows machine...Thanks for taking care.

Comment: You don't provided windows tag, so this is a Linux answer. You can try in WSL, Cygwin or git bash

Answer (score 0):

I had finally succeeded to accomplish this through a bat file, below is my code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Create an empty merged file
type nul > merged_file.txt

REM Loop through each text file
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    REM Extract filename without extension
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    
    REM Append each line with filename to merged file
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%%f) do (
        echo %%i#!filename!.txt>> merged_file.txt
    )
)

echo Merging completed.
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**